# Is there an R function for returning sorted indexes of any values of a vector?

Tags: r, function, sorting, data.table, row

I'm not fluent in R data.table and any help will be greatly appreciated to resolve the following problem !
I have big data.table(~1000000 rows) with columns  of numeric values and i want to output a same dimension data.table with the sorted indexes position of each row values.

a short example:

-Input:

```
dt = data.frame(ack = 1:7)

dt$A1 = c( 1,    6,  9,  10,  3,   5, NA)
dt$A2 = c( 25,  12, 30,  10, 50,   1, 30)
dt$A3 = c( 100, 63, 91, 110,  1,   4, 10)
dt$A4 = c( 51,  65,  2,   1,  0, 200,  1)
```

first row: 1 (**1**) <= 25 (**2**) <= 51 (**3**) <= 100 (**4**),
row sorted indexes position  for (1, 25, 100, 51) are (1, 2, 4, 3) and output should be:

```
dt$PosA1 = c(1, ...
dt$PosA2 = c(2, ...
dt$PosA3 = c(4, ...
dt$PosA4 = c(3, ...
```

3rd row :  2 (**1**) <= 9 (**2**) <= 30 (**3**) <= 91 (**4**) , must output:

```
dt$PosA1 = c( 1,1,2,...)
dt$PosA2 = c( 2,2,3,...)
dt$PosA3 = c( 4,3,4,...)
dt$PosA4 = c( 3,4,1,...)
```

Output is a same dimension of input data.table filled with values of sorted indexes by rows .

```
dt$PosA1 = c( 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, NA)
dt$PosA2 = c( 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 2, 3)
dt$PosA3 = c( 4, 3, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2)
dt$PosA4 = c( 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1)
```

I think about perhaps something like this?

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dt)

# pseudocode
dt[, PosA1 := rowPosition(.SD, 1, na.rm=T),
     PosA2 := rowPosition(.SD, 2, na.rm=T),
     PosA3 := rowPosition(.SD, 3, na.rm=T),
     PosA4 := rowPosition(.SD, 4, na.rm=T),
     .SDcols=c(A1, A2, A3, A4)]
```

I'm not sure of syntax and i miss a rowPosition Function. does any function exist to do that ? (i named it rowPosition here)

A little help would be great to code an efficient one , or another approach to solve the problem!

regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are looking for speed, you might want to consider using Rcpp. A Rcpp `rank` that takes care of NA and ties can be found in [nrussell's adapted version of René Richter's code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39153082/rcpp-rank-function-that-does-average-ties/39170596#39170596).

```
nr <- 811e3
nc <- 16
DT <- as.data.table(matrix(sample(c(1:200, NA), nr*nc, replace=TRUE), nrow=nr))[, 
    ack := .I]

#assuming that you have saved nrussell code in avg_rank.cpp
library(Rcpp)
system.time(sourceCpp("rcpp/avg_rank.cpp"))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.00    0.13    6.21 

nruss_rcpp <- function() {
    DT[, as.list(avg_rank(unlist(.SD))), by=ack]
}

data.table.frank <- function() {
    melt(DT, id="ack")[, f := frank(value, na.last="keep", ties.method="dense"), by=ack][, 
        dcast(.SD, ack ~ variable, value.var="f")]
}


library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(nruss_rcpp(), data.table.frank(), times=3L)
```

timings:

```
Unit: seconds
               expr       min        lq     mean   median        uq       max neval cld
       nruss_rcpp()  10.33032  10.33251  10.3697  10.3347  10.38939  10.44408     3  a 
 data.table.frank() 610.44869 612.82685 613.9362 615.2050 615.68001 616.15501     3   b
```

---

edit: addressing comments

**1)** set column names for rank columns using updating by reference

```
DT[, (paste0("Rank", 1L:nc)) := as.list(avg_rank(unlist(.SD))), by=ack]
```

**2)** keeping NAs as it is

*option A)* change to NA in R after getting output from `avg_rank`:

```
for (j in 1:nc) {
    DT[is.na(get(paste0("V", j))), (paste0("Rank", j)) := NA_real_]
}
```

*option B)* amend the `avg_rank` code in Rcpp as follows:

```
Rcpp::NumericVector avg_rank(Rcpp::NumericVector x)
{
    R_xlen_t sz = x.size();
    Rcpp::IntegerVector w = Rcpp::seq(0, sz - 1);
    std::sort(w.begin(), w.end(), Comparator(x));

    Rcpp::NumericVector r = Rcpp::no_init_vector(sz);
    for (R_xlen_t n, i = 0; i < sz; i += n) {
        n = 1;
        while (i + n < sz && x[w[i]] == x[w[i + n]]) ++n;
        for (R_xlen_t k = 0; k < n; k++) {
            if (Rcpp::traits::is_na<REALSXP>(x[w[i + k]])) {  #additional code
                r[w[i + k]] = NA_REAL;                        #additional code
            } else {
                r[w[i + k]] = i + (n + 1) / 2.;
            }
        }
    }

    return r;
}
```

Comment: hello @chinsoon12, should be great but i don't now how avg_rank can be available from my Rstudio envt  (library(Rcpp) is not sufficient , and i don't know  how to ```` ```#assuming that you have saved nrussell code in avg_rank.cpp```.

Comment: sorry for my low-level knowledge in R :(

Comment: I red TFM, got Rtool installed and source avg_rank.cpp and launch again and.... Greaaaaaat !!! 20s instead 8mn !!!! If I can abuse. I would like NA value stay NA and keep Columns name instead V1...VN. Thx a lot !!!!!!

Comment: You got so far in a few hours. These last 2 questions are nothing to you.

Comment: :)) thanks too encourage me to read harder. I resolve "columns" question (dt[, (cols) = ....]), but inspecting and modifying  nrussel code is too hard for me at the moment. So i can get around in looking for a way to compare values of result table and orig and print result values if not NA else NA. But the smart way, in one call, would be to give avg_rank( ) a parameter like na.last = "keep" to take this exception in count).

Comment: R was unknown to me 2 month ago and make me headache but i progress at 55 year old for my datascience formation. It's my first time too on stackoverflow and it's just an amazing  
 source to guide me in this learning. I can learn C++ too if anybody can give me some little help. But the gap for me to do the job with the nrussel's code seems too high. Anyway thanks a lot for previous help.

Comment: @Pascal, sorry for the late reply. I edited the post and added some codes to address your comments.

Answer (score 3):

You can convert to long form and use `rank`. Or, since you're using data.table, `frank`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dt)
melt(dt, id="ack")[, f := frank(value, na.last="keep", ties.method="dense"), by=ack][, 
  dcast(.SD, ack ~ variable, value.var="f")]

   ack A1 A2 A3 A4
1:   1  1  2  4  3
2:   2  1  2  3  4
3:   3  2  3  4  1
4:   4  2  2  3  1
5:   5  3  4  2  1
6:   6  3  1  2  4
7:   7 NA  3  2  1
```

`melt` switches to long form; while `dcast` converts back to wide form.

Comment: Thx @Frank , but i encounter an error: ```Error in melt.data.table(dt, id = "ack") : 
  One or more values in 'id.vars' is invalid.```

Comment: @Pascal You will need to create a row-ID column, like `dt[, ack := .I]` or `dt$ack <- seq_len(nrow(dt))`. I'm using the code from your post after I edited it so that it is copy-pastable. You can look above to see what I mean. Of course, you don't need to name it ack :)

Comment: But if I Sys.time() on my data.table (811000 x 16 ) and take about 8mn on a 4 Core I5 vPro 8th Gen  , 16Go RAM.  Is there a way to optimize this duration or i should consider it's a good count ?

Comment: @Pascal I agree -- 8 minutes for this sort of thing seems like too long. You can wait for further answers. Hopefully, someone else will have a better idea and post it here.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution ! i wil take lot of coffee cup i waiting for better :)!